# Find bug in implementation of algorithm that finds minimum of an array of integers

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

Recently, I tried to write a Java program which searches for the minimum of an array.
I tried to write it in a different way, I know there are more simple ways to do that but I want to know why my program does not work.

Here is the source code :

```
public int minimum(int [] t) {
    int min,i,j;
    i=j=t.length/2;
    min=t[t.length/2];
    while(j!=0 || i!=t.length-1) {
        while( t[i]>=min) {
            i++;
            if(i==t.length) {
                i=t.length-1;
                continue;
            }
        }
        while(t[j]>=min) {
            j--;
            if(j==-1) {
                j=0;
                continue;
            }
        }
        if(t[i]<=min && t[j]<=min) {
            if(t[i]<=t[j]) min=t[i];
            else min=t[j];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: im sorry for the title i forget to change it

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: i got no error, its clean but not working

Answer (score 0):

Before you read the answer you should try debugging your code to figure this out by yourself.
I think your code loops infinitely in one of those inner `while` loops because the end condition

`if(i==t.length) {
    i=t.length-1;
    continue;
 }`

only resets the `i` one step back and the `continue` restarts the `while` loop. You probably meant to have the `break` keyword there instead of the `continue` in which case your code will continue with the other inner while loop.

Comment: hello ,yeah u are right in this note, i got confused between continue and break .thanks for the note .

Answer (score 0):

there is some logic errors in my code , and it get infinitely going through the two loops , i fixed the loops by changing continue with break and i modify the last condition by setting || instead of && (that was a logic mistake), and it works now .
thanks guys.
here is the new source code:

```
public int minimum(int [] t) {
    int min,i,j;
    i=j=t.length/2;
    min=t[t.length/2];
    while(j!=0 || i!=t.length-1) {
        while( t[i]>=min) {
            i++;
            if(i==t.length) {
                i=t.length-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        while(t[j]>=min) {
            j--;
            if(j==-1) {
                j=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(t[i]<=min || t[j]<=min) {
            if(t[i]<=t[j]) min=t[i];
            else min=t[j];
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```